# Problem with debug="false"

Tags: web-applications, iis-7, web-config

I have a program and it works well with debug="true" in web.config.
When i want to get the good version i put debug="false". When i open 2 (or 3 or 4, it's aleatory) selection window (pop windows) i have a timeout error.

I have read if debug is true  property is not taken into account. But i have set this value to "900" and the error persist.

Another way to get the error?

I'm with vista and IIS7.

*Edited: I have changed the pipeline to classic instead of integrated and it works well. Any reason?

Comment: I have changed the pipeline to classic instead of integrated and it works well. Any reason?

Answer (score 1):

Settinng debug=true essentially forces the web server to run single-threaded for debugging purposes - it serializes requests and that tends to hide multi-threaded problems. It's tough to speculate about what might be wrong without more detail about your application.